# Elasticsearch - Return records with parent that has given attributes, or no parent at all

Tags: elasticsearch

I am upgrading an application that started with Elasticsearch 0.9 to 5.5 and need to find a way to re-implement the expected behavior.

There is an index with a mapping like this:

```
{
  'parent' => {
    'properties' => {
      'boolean_attribute' => {
        'type' => 'bool
      }
    }
  },
  'actual_doc_name' => {
    '_parent' => {
      'type' => 'parent'
    },
    'properties' => {
      'title' => {
        'type' => 'string'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The original application behavior has these mapped to two models in Rails (Parent and ActualDocName, let's say). When a parent is deleted, an ActualDocName is still a valid object. When a parent is present, I often want to find an ActualDocName where the ActualDocName's Parent has a 'boolean_attribute' => 'false'. So I set up a `has_parent` query:

```
{
  'query' => {
    'bool' => {
      'must' => [
        { 'has_parent' => {
          'type' => 'parent',
          'filter' => {
            'term' => { 'boolean_attribute' => 'F' }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is great. It returns ActualDocName records that have a Parent where 'boolean_attribute' is false.

But I need to include, in the same result set, ActualDocName records that *do not have a parent at all*. So the only ActualDocName records I want to exclude are ones that both have a parent AND have a parent where the parent's boolean_attribute is false.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding `parent_boolean_attribute` to the ActualDocName index. It fixed my problem, though I don't know that it's the best solution.